# 3-headed display with Dell Latitude D630 & port replicator possible?

Tags: multiple-monitors, dell-latitude

A Dell D630 with port replicator has the laptop's LCD screen, plus add'l VGA and DVI.  I know either the VGA or DVI ports work for second screens, but can both the VGA and DVI be employed for 3 screens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use two of the three displays at any given time.

Comment: This is correct. In a office scenario with the docking station, you can use two monitors(one each with VGA and DVI), but then you cannot use the onboard LCD itself. Pick two out of three

Comment: How about the s-video out, does this apply to the 2 of the 3?

Comment: I seriously doubt it. I believe the video circuitry on has two RAMDAC (or the digital equivalent). If you need more video outputs I would suggest the USB variants to add another. Check out the kits at http://sewelldirect.com/

Comment: Or one of the lattitude-D docks with room for a PCI card. A low power PCI graphics card might just do the trick.  (though finding anything which is PCI and not PCI-e might be a challenge).